# No such file or directory: '/dev/hidraw0'

Tags: python, directory, raspberry-pi, drive, pi

I have two QRCode scanners, raspberry pi hidraw0/hidraw1. QRCode scanner is connected to raspberry pi and when will scan more than 100 QRcode frequently after that anyone qrcode scanner stop reading the input. It's giving `No such file or directory: 'dev/hidraw0' error.

After restarting the controller both scanner are working fine. Anybody know what could be the reason why the hidraw* port are changing.

```
def verify_qr():

    global xC1
    global done

    while not done:
        print ("Inside While Not Done loop in verify qr")

        hid = {4: 'a', 5: 'b', 6: 'c', 7: 'd', 8: 'e', 9: 'f', 10: 'g', 11: 'h', 12: 'i', 13: 'j', 14: 'k', 15: 'l', 16: 'm',
               17: 'n', 18: 'o', 19: 'p', 20: 'q', 21: 'r', 22: 's', 23: 't', 24: 'u', 25: 'v', 26: 'w', 27: 'x', 28: 'y',
               29: 'z', 30: '1', 31: '2', 32: '3', 33: '4', 34: '5', 35: '6', 36: '7', 37: '8', 38: '9', 39: '0', 44: ' ',
               45: '-', 46: '=', 47: '[', 48: ']', 49: '\\', 51: ';', 52: '\'', 53: '~', 54: ',', 55: '.', 56: '/'}

        hid2 = {4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'D', 8: 'E', 9: 'F', 10: 'G', 11: 'H', 12: 'I', 13: 'J', 14: 'K', 15: 'L', 16: 'M',
                17: 'N', 18: 'O', 19: 'P', 20: 'Q', 21: 'R', 22: 'S', 23: 'T', 24: 'U', 25: 'V', 26: 'W', 27: 'X', 28: 'Y',
                29: 'Z', 30: '!', 31: '@', 32: '#', 33: '$', 34: '%', 35: '^', 36: '&', 37: '*', 38: '(', 39: ')', 44: ' ',
                45: '_', 46: '+', 47: '{', 48: '}', 49: '|', 51: ':', 52: '"', 53: '~', 54: '<', 55: '>', 56: '?'}
        fp = open('/dev/hidraw0', 'rb')

        print ("hidraw0 File Opened")
        ss = ""

        shift = False
```

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in the line **fp = open('/dev/hidraw0', 'rb')**  the path mentioned by you is not recognized by open function as it is incomplete path.Kindly give full path when you read file in binary mode.